# nodejs process to handle sigterm and propagate sigterm

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

Looking to trap a sigterm and propagate it to next sigterm associate with same process.

I have a express application which is instrumented using a 3rd party package to obtain performance metrics

```
const express = require('express');
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const thirdpartyAPM = require('....'); 


// app
const app = express();
...
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('Trap sigterm message and close app connections');
  ... // Some app related activity
  // <--- need help here to propagate to 3rd party code to wrap its activity
}); 

app.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

Please note the 3rd party app depends on SIGTERM trapping to wrap its activity as well and I want to wrap the SIGTERM in my app code as well.

**What solution help is expected here**

1. Trap sigterm at my code first to perform some app activity closure
2. Propagate sigterm further so that the 3rd party app can trap the SIGTERM AGAIN.

I tried process.exit(code); this do not help in propagating sigterm.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('Trap sigterm first');
  // pass the sigterm to next trap
});
.....
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('Trap sigterm second time');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're probably looking for [`process.kill()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processkillpid-signal)